# Issue with tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8

I changed date of Linux machine to `Sat Jul 13 00:26:56 IST 2019` using date command. Post that I am receiving below error in Tomcat Catalina

```
java.security.KeyStoreException: Uninitialized keystore
```

Comment: Please garner your questions with a *specific* title.

Comment: Appologies,i know it's quite vague but stack overflow is blocking me from adding date change causing keystore issue in tomcat

Comment: The use case here is my data is of May and I cannot transform it to current IST time stamp. So was thinking if by any means the current system can be changed to May or July and get tomcat working